# I want to compare 2 arrays. Why it doesn`t work?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

```
// I have got an array; 
//var resultArray = t.getElementsForTable(1);

var expectedArray = ['0'];

it("if expected array equal to the actual", function () {
    assert.strictEqual(t.getElementsForTable(1), expectedArray);
});
```

Comment: Because `t.getElementsForTable(1);` will never be equal to `['0']`.

Comment: How to compare 2 arrays, using unit-testing

Comment: getElementsForTable(1) returns array - ["0"] !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use deep equal if you are trying to compare the values inside array.

```
.deepEqual(actual, expected, [message])
```

Source: http://chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_deepequal